# How do I send multiple Ctrl-C signals without releasing Ctrl key in Windows?

Tags: windows, special-characters

My setup is a Windows 11 workstation running Putty to connect to an embedded device over FTDI USB-serial adapter. For most cases this works flawlessly.

The failing bit is when I need to send multiple Ctrl-C commands very fast. While holding Ctrl, I press c repeatedly, but only the first two Ctrl-C arrive. After this, only the c character is sent. It can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of misbehaving Putty session]

Of course this can be avoided by not holding Ctrl and pressing both repeatedly, but then I don't send it as fast as I need.

I replicated the behavior in PowerShell, which tells me that this is not a Putty thing but a Windows thing.

Why does it behave like this? And can it be configured to send Ctrl-C signal repeatedly without releasing the Ctrl key?

---

Some background on why I need this: I need to interrupt the embedded device boot. The bootloader is configured to interrupt on Ctrl-C, and only has a very short window of opportunity to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs look at the state of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key when checking the press of the <kbd>c</kbd> key. These would work fine in your case.

It is possible that some programs are looking at events. That is checking that an event arrived on the press of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then an event on tbe press of the <kbd>c</kbd> key. These will not get the subsequent events for the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

My suggestion is to increase the **Auto-Repeat Rate**. This may make it work for you.

P.S. the reason the second one works is probably that you are slow to press the 2nd **C** as compared to the third. So the auto- repeat gets in another <kbd>ctrl</kbd> press event.